# What is the purpose of Ruby array's methods assoc and rassoc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I've read the documentation of the methods `assoc` and `rassoc` of Ruby `array`. I understand what they do. They both work on arrays of arrays. `assoc` returns the array whose first element equals the provided parameter, and `rassoc` does the same, but for the second element.

My question is what are these methods for? This functionality is very specific. I'm guessing there is some reason why these methods were created. what is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons, but the main one is so that an Array can act like a Hash. I think that because Hashes are unsorted, the Ruby designers needed a way to represent a hash in an ordered fashion. I think that there are a lot of `Enumerable` methods that return arrays when invoked on a hash.

Comment: Equivalent functions are found in Lisp; perhaps that's where Ruby got them.

Comment: Since version 1.9, Ruby hashes are guaranteed to iterate in insertion order. (I agree with you, though).

Comment: @johncip: I was under the impression that that new hash behavior wasn't universal (as in, relying on it might give problems in, say, JRuby).

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the behavior was left unspecified before 1.9, but preserving insertion order became part of the spec, so I'd expect recent versions of all implementations to support it. But I only use MRI Ruby.