# How to check if a key exists in an array of arrays?

Tags: ruby

Is there a straightforward way to do something like the following without excessive looping?

```
myArray = [["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"]]
if myArray.includes?("c")
   ...
```

I know this works fine if it's just a normal array of chars... but I would like something equally as elegant for an array of an array of chars (bonus points for helping convert this to an array of tuples).

Comment: What do you mean by "key"? Do you just want to check if the item exists in any of the sub-arrays, or are you treating the sub-arrays as key-value pairs and so want to check if the item exists in the first position in any of the sub-arrays?

Comment: I cannot recommend this, but if, as in the example, all elements of `myArray` are of the same size, you could write, `require 'array'; m = Matrix[*myArray]; m.index("f") #=> [2,1]; m.index("g") #=> nil`,  `[2,1]` being truthy.

Comment: In case you're just coming to Ruby from another language, one Ruby convention is to use snake-case for names of variables and methods, so `myArray` would generally be written `my_array`. Snake-case is lower-case letters and underscores, and in the case of method names, the last character can be `"?"` or `"!"`. You don't have to adopt that convention, but 99%+ of Rubiests do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only need a true/false answer you can [flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) the array and call include on that:

```
>> myArray.flatten.include?("c")
=> true
```

Comment: ...or `myArray.flatten.index("c")`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, good point! For those interested, the difference is that `index` returns the position of "c" in the array (or `nil` if "c" isn't found), whereas `include?` only returns `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`assoc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-assoc):

```
my_array = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]

if my_array.assoc('c')
  # ...
```

It actually returns the whole subarray:

```
my_array.assoc('c') #=> ["c", "d"]
```

or `nil` if there is no match:

```
my_array.assoc('g') #=> nil
```

There's also [`rassoc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-rassoc) to search for the second element:

```
my_array.rassoc('d') #=> ["c", "d"]
```

Comment: I was curious why we have those two methods. For those interested, this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922454/what-is-the-purpose-of-ruby-arrays-methods-assoc-and-rassoc) and [blog entry](http://blog.honeybadger.io/associative-arrays-in-ruby-what/) shed some light on that.

Answer (score 3):

```
my_array  = [["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"]]
p my_hash = my_array.to_h # => {"a"=>"b", "c"=>"d", "e"=>"f"}
p my_hash.key?("c") #  => true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#any?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/any%3F)

```
myArray = [["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"]]
if myArray.any? { |x| x.includes?("c") }
  # some code here
```

Answer (score 1):

The `find_index` method works well for this:

```
myArray = [["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"]]
puts "found!" if myArray.find_index {|a| a[0] == "c" }
```

The return value is the array index of the pair or `nil` if the pair is not found.

You can capture the pair's value (or `nil` if not found) this way:

```
myArray.find_index {|a| a[0] == "c" } || [nil, nil])[1]
# => "d"
```